# Python GUI list with progress bar

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, progress-bar

I'm trying to make a list where a row has some data that can be represented as text, where the row is selectable, and can contain a progressbar.  I can't figure out how to implement this with tkinter, I can set up a selectable list with a treeview element, and a progressbar with the progressbar element.  But I can't put them together.  While I'm using tkinter right now, I'm open to other packages that would support this.  Here's the layout I've been working off of https://i.stack.imgur.com/766hn.png

Comment: AFAIK you can't have other widgets inside a `ttk.Treeview` item, only text. You can simulate it, for example by gridding widgets in a `Frame` but it could be a lot of work to replicate all functionality.. I am pretty sure you an do this with more advanced toolkits like GTK or Qt but I don't know the details.

Comment: You can make a selectable list with a tkinter [ListBox](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/listbox.html). Here's and image of one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pf7or.png

Comment: @martineau you can't put progressbars inside ListBox items either.

Comment: An idea of using a `Frame` widget, mentioned by @Goyo, is very usefull in your case. However, he's also right about a lot of work, but this statement is subjective, I think that anyone, who's familiar with tkinter, can achieve this in one day, or couple of if you lazy, so don't be afraid of work. My suggestion is to look over [PanedWindow](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/panedwindow.html) widget, instead of frame (a PanedWindow of PanedWindows in your case). He's give to you more control over childs and gives a table-like functionality from the box, hence less things to code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've been doing some googling.  GTK on windows with python 3 is pretty hard to set up, so I'm messing with Qt now instead to see if I like it.  I've also been looking at a few ways to achieve this with tkinter, and I agree with @CommonSense that it would be possible, but maybe not easy.  I'm still learning tkinter, and this is very much a learning project, so I think it will probably take me a few days.